# How to enforce two classes to have the same certain set of variables without inheritance, with annotations?

Tags: java

I have classes `Product`and `ProductImage`
I want them both to have the following set of booleans: `toBeSynced`, `toBeAdded` and `toBeDeleted`

How can I enforce that using some OOP Design pattern? I thought of interfaces but those are for meethods. I dont want them to extend a `Syncable` class because it doesnt feel right. I dont want to manually add those booleans to both classes, I want the booleans to come from somewhere else.

EDIT: I understood that this can be achieved by annotations. How would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is through inheritance, by using an abstract class to define  the common properties.

if it does not feel right, your naming and/or design is probably incorrect

```
abstract class Syncable {

    boolean toBeSynced;
    boolean toBeAdded;
    boolean toBeDeleted;

    abstract void sync();
    abstract void add();
    abstract void delete();
}
```

**Product**:

```
class Product extends Syncable {
    // impl...
}
```

**ProductImage**:

```
class ProductImage extends Syncable {
    // impl...
}
```

**EDIT:**

You should really think about what your classes are going to do, i.e *is-a (inheritance)* vs *has-a (composition)* relationships, for example:

*is* a `Product` a `Syncable` versus does a `Product` *have* a `Sync` object;

in the same way you would think of a Car, does a car have wheels, or is it a wheel? i think not ;)

Comment: thank you, I will try that, if I dont find another way. Do you know whether I could do this using annotations?

Comment: definitely, but then you will need to write annotation processing code. the composition example is also a good one

Answer (score 3):

You may use composition if you want:

```
class Sync {
   boolean toBeSynced, toBeAdded ,toBeDeleted
}

class Product {
    Sync sync;
}

class ProductImage {
    Sync sync;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use composition to "mixin" the values that you want.

For example, we can have a class called Syncable, which has the values you want.

```
public class Syncable
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private boolean toBeSynced;

   public void setToBeSynced(boolean toBeSynced){
       this.toBeSynced = toBeSynced;
    }

    public boolean getToBeSynced(){
        return this.toBeSynced;
    }
}
```

Then, in your product class for example

```
public class Product
{
    Syncable sync;
    public Product()
    {
        sync = new Syncable();

    }

}
```

After doing this, you can modify the boolean values as you wish.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Product p = new Product();
        p.sync.setToBeSynced(false);
        System.out.println(p.sync.getToBeSynced());
}
```

Of course, you may wish to add another layer of abstraction with methods in the product class that can set and get the boolean values that you want.

For example, you could add the following 2 methods to the product class:

```
public void setBoolean(boolean bool){
    this.sync.setToBeSynced(bool);
}

public boolean getBoolean(){
    return this.sync.getToBeSynced();
}
```

Then, in another part of your program, you could state

```
Product p = new Product();
p.setBoolean(true);
boolean bool = p.getBoolean();
```